# Custom keyboard doesn't load on device

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I'm doing a custom keyboard for iOS and am pretty much finished. However, I did the debugging on the simulator, but when I tried to run it on a device, the keyboard simply won't load. The device is running on iOS 8.

I don't think I'm using any non-Cocoa Touch classes that would run on the simulator but not on a device. Also, the debugger won't attach to the app, so I don't know what's happening for sure. The view where the keyboard should be does show, but no content appears or is there a background color change.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

It's quite common even in iOS 8 GM.

Try to remove the keyboard in Settings, restart your phone and add the keyboard again. That works for me most of the time.